# WaitForSingleObject signals too soon ImageMagick convert

Tags: c++, winapi, process, cmd, synchronous

I'm converting PDFs to JPGs using ImageMagick.  This conversion takes a couple hundred milliseconds to run, so I've got a [WaitForSingleItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) waiting on the process handle.

Unfortunately, the process finishes almost immediately, and the conversion doesn't complete (I'm assuming it's interrupted due to the handles being closed).  I want synchronous behavior.

I've got an output pipe connected to the process, and I don't get any output at all, 
errors or otherwise, since the process thinks "OK, done, close everything up and move on."

With a less intensive operation, everything works as expected - errors, outputs, etc. - I think the problem is almost definitely in the waiting.

Can someone make a suggestion on how to fix this?  Here's some applicable code, probably not very helpful, but it's the only part that matters since everything else works just fine.

After I run the code, I get the message `WAIT_OBJECT_0`.

```
if (!CreateProcess(
    NULL, 
    (LPSTR) "convert test.pdf test.jpg",
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &si,
    &pi
    )) { console_->AddItem("ERROR: Failed to create process."); }

DWORD wait = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
if (wait == WAIT_ABANDONED)     { MessageBox(NULL, "WAIT_ABANDONED", "Alert", MB_OK); }
else if (wait == WAIT_OBJECT_0) { MessageBox(NULL, "WAIT_OBJECT_0", "Alert", MB_OK); }
else if (wait == WAIT_TIMEOUT)  { MessageBox(NULL, "WAIT_TIMEOUT", "Alert", MB_OK); }
else if (wait == WAIT_FAILED)   { MessageBox(NULL, "WAIT_FAILED", "Alert", MB_OK); }
else                            { MessageBox(NULL, "END OF THE WORLD", "Alert", MB_OK); }
```

Comment: Are you positive that the command that takes a lot longer "more intensive" actually works and doesn't error out?

Comment: Yes, I've tested separately in `cmd` also, and I've been using that command in different languages for years now.  Also, I've tried other "less intensive" commands with intentional errors, and they come down the pipe with no problems.

Comment: What does GetExitCodeProcess return?

Comment: GetExitCodeProcess returns 4, so the problem must be in the command. I've removed the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag and there's some funny business there - thanks for the hints that may be it.  Back in a few.

Comment: You are using relative paths in your command, even to the "convert" executable itself. You should be using absolute paths for everything instead. At least that will eliminate one point of possible failure.

Comment: You should also get rid of the `LPSTR` type-cast. It is unnecessary in the code you showed, and will hide a logic bug in your code if you ever upgrade your code to use `CreateProcessW()` instead of `CreateProcessA()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake, unrelated to WINAPI. Everything was working as it should.

http://support.cs.nott.ac.uk/help/docs/image/ImageMagick/www/FAQ.html#C19

ImageMagick has a `convert` command but so does Windows, so it's using the wrong bloody one.

When I did it via `cmd` directly, it worked as expected, but for some reason via `CreateProcess`, the wrong `convert.exe` was used.  Don't know why that is but it's easy enough to fix.

A funny little jab from ImageMagick: `The Windows convert.exe program is used to convert a system boot disk from MS-DOS "FAT" format to NTFS format. As such it can only be used one time in the life of a system.`

Thanks @jeremy for the helpful hints.

Comment: All the more reason NEVER to rely on relative paths an ALWAYS use absolute paths instead.